# how to pull a string from a list of objects in python

Tags: python, string, time

```
import os; import time; 

not_command_error = "error: not an command"
empty_error = "error: file empty"

def read(file):
  e = open(file, "r")
  b = e.readlines()
  e.close()
  return b

code_file = "put your code here"

e = read(code_file)
if e == []:
  print("\033[0;37;41m",empty_error)
  time.sleep(90000)
count = len(e)
print(count)
g = 0
l = 0
while True:
  
  l+= 1
  t = open(code_file, "r")
  y = t.readlines(l)
  t.close()
  k = len(y)
  print(y[k])
  u = y[k]
  
  g+= 1
  if count == g:
    
    break
```

this is my code, and I get and index out of range error, any help?
i tried changing the format and it still didn't work.
i get index out of range error, do i not use a variable?

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code will throw an index out of range error:

```py
k = len(y)
print(y[k])
```

Indices for lists in Python go from `0` to `len(x) - 1`, so to access the last element, `k` should equal `len(y) - 1`.

Even better (thanks, @MarkK!), you can use [negative indices](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=negative%20slice#subscriptions) to access the end of the array:

```py
print(y[-1])
```

Comment: Or, better yet, `y[-1]` and forget about `k`.